# Is there a way to modify files inside docker via PyCharm?

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

I want to modify files inside docker container with PyCharm. Is there possibility of doing such thing?

Comment: Any change you make this way will get lost as soon as you delete and recreate a container.  This is extremely routine to change container options, update the base image, _etc._  It’s better practice (and much easier!) to do development outside of Docker, and `docker build` a new image when you need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to obtain is called Bind Mounting and it can be obtained adding **-v** parameter to your run command, here's an example with an nginx image:

```
docker run --name=nginx -d -v ~/nginxlogs:/var/log/nginx -p 5000:80 nginx
```

The specific parameter obtaining this result is **-v**.

`-v ~/nginxlogs:/var/log/nginx` sets up a bindmount volume that links the `/var/log/nginx` directory from inside the Nginx container to the `~/nginxlogs` directory on the host machine.
 Docker uses a : to split the host’s path from the container path, and the host path always comes first.

In other words the files that you edit on your local filesystem will be synced to the Docker folder immediately.

[Source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-the-docker-container-and-the-host)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are multiple ways to do this, and you will need to have PyCharm installed inside the container.

Following set of instructions should work -

> `docker ps` - *This will show you details of running containers*
>
> `docker exec -it *<name of container>* /bin/bash`

At this point you will oh shell inside the container. If PyCharm is not installed, you will need to install. Following should work -

`sudo apt-get install pycharm-community`

Good to go!

**Note:** The installation is not persistence across Docker image builds. You should add the installation step of PyCharm on DockerFile if you need to access it regularly.

Comment: bash: sudo: command not found

But I still want to achieve something else. PyCharm has possibility to connect to remote server, edit files and run sript from there. I would like to modify files in locally installed PyCharm and run script inside docker